# Is it polite to send an email to check if a proposal has been submitted?

Tags: etiquette, postdocs, email

A few months ago I prepared the proposal for a national postdoctoral fellowship, and I would like to check if it has been successfully submitted (the guest institution had a deadline we -my possible supervisor and I- weren't aware of until it passed). Do you think an email like the one below is a polite (and not overformal) request for news? Thanks.

> Dear Prof. ZZ,
>
> I just wanted to check whether you had a chance to submit the XX Fellowship proposal we prepared (an internal deadline of the University of YY popped up at the last moment).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a polite and simple check-in like you write should probably be just fine.